# WPML : how to pick a featured image only once for different languages?

Tags: attachments, multi-language, plugin-wpml

I've got 3 languages on my site. Picking the same featured image 3 times for the 3 versions of each article is boring. Is there any way to do it only once ? (same for picking a tag)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll find the answer here : http://wpml.org/2011/05/new-plugin-wpml-media-translation/

Comment: Always post the answer, and not just a link, for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

WPML -> Media Translation -> How to add media for new content -> uncheck "When uploading media to the Media library, make it available in all languages"